# Why if the columns of $Q$ are an orthonormal basis for $F^n$ then $Q$ is unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why if the columns of $Q$ are an orthonormal basis for $F^n$ then $Q$ is unitary?
There exist any available theorems to prove it?

Comment: No theorems needed. Think about matrix multiplication and the entries of $Q^*Q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to see it. If the columns form an orthonormal basis, you can directly check that $QQ^\ast = Q^\ast Q = I$. So $Q^{-1} = Q^\ast$. Then we can compute what $Q$ does to norms using the inner product: $$\begin{align*} \|a\|^2 &= (a,a) \\
&= (Ia, a) \\
&= (Q^{-1}Qa,a) \\
&= (Q^\ast Qa,a) \\
&= (Qa, Qa) \\
&= \|Qa\|^2 \end{align*}$$ and so $Q$ preserves norms and is bijective since it has an inverse.

Answer (score 1):

With $Q=(q_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^n$ the equation $Q^*Q=I$ becomes explicitly
$$
  \sum_{k=1}^n \overline{q_{k,i}}q_{k,j}=\delta_{i,j}
 \qquad\text{for all $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$,}
$$
which just says that columns $i,j$ of $Q$ are orthogonal for $i\neq j$, and that their scalar product is$~1$ when $i=j$.